# Place a formula in every cell in column N for which there is a value two columns to the left

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

How do I place a formula in every cell in column N for which there is a value two columns to the left (in column L)?

```
 Sub KeepOnlyAtSymbolRows()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim rng1, rng2 As Range
        Dim lastRow, LASTROW2 As Long

    LASTROW2 = ws.Range("L" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         Set rng2 = ws.Range("L2" & LASTROW2)
         'Debug.Print rng2
         For Each cell In rng2
            cell.offset()
            cell.Formula = "foo bar etc"
            Next cell
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
Sub KeepOnlyAtSymbolRows()
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim LASTROW2 As Long
    LASTROW2 = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng2 = Range("N1:N" & LASTROW2)
    For Each cell In rng2
        If cell.Offset(0, -2) <> "" Then
        cell.Formula = "foo bar etc"
        End If
     Next cell
End Sub
```

You seem not to be applying `rng1` nor `lastRow` and not setting the `ws` value anyway. And if you were and wanted to dimension as Range/Long then in VBA you need to [Pay Attention To Variables Declared With One Dim Statement](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx).

You are trying to set `rng2` with syntax that would give something like `L29` if `9` is your last occupied row in ColumnL.

Since I think it is ColumnN you want to populate I think `rng2` should be based on that, even if using ColumnL to determine the last populated row.

It seems you want a conditional (`<> ""` is interpreted as "not blank") and `.offset` needs parameters (`(0,-2)` is interpreted as "same row, two columns to the left").